# Spring controller that accepts both MultipartFile and also a JSON Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I need to make a POST endpoint in Java Springboot that accepts a MultipartFile (a raw file like xlsx, doc that we can upload from windows explorer) and also a JSON Object (metadata).
The JSON Object will be provided as a String, like:

```
{
  "address": "string",
  "fullName": "string"
}
```

I tried the following:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/post", consumes = {"application/json","multipart/form-data"})
  public ResponseEntity<String> endpoint(
    @RequestBody ReportDto reportDto,
    @RequestPart("myFile") MultipartFile myFile
  ){
  return ResponseEntity.ok(service.process(reportDto,myFile));
  }
```

ReportDto used in controller:

```
 public class ReportDto{
  
  String address;
  String fullName;
    //getters
    //setters
    //all arg constructor
    //no arg constructor
  
  }
```

When I try to hit the endpoint through Swagger or through POSTMAN, i get **HTTP 415 : Unsupported Media** error.

My CURL request looks like this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dashboards/post' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer somebearertoken' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'reportDto={
  "address": "string",
  "fullName": "string"
}' \
  -F 'myFile=@Table_New.xlsx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

Please help me on resolving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the controller method like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/post", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> endpoint(
        @RequestPart ReportDto reportDto,
        @RequestPart MultipartFile myFile) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.process(reportDto, myFile));
}
```

Please note: the name attribute in the annotation RequestPart is not required if it matches the parameter name. Please also note that using the constants defined in MediaType helps avoid typo/mistakes.

You should also add the media type definition for reportDto to your CURL/Postman request:

```
-F 'reportDto={
    "address": "string",
    "fullName": "string"};
    type=application/json'
```

Comment: it now throws "Unsupported media type: application/octet-stream"

Comment: This is because the media type is not set for reportDto. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Wrong Answer]Http request must have exact body data type, like json, xml, html.So you can't put two kind of data in http body.
You can transfer the params by url, and transfer file data by body.

Comment: but if the params i.e ReportDto has 100s of fields, wont the URL look ugly? or is it completely ok?

Comment: @fengyadong it's not true. multipart/form-data is exactly the media type for the use case in question. As the name says it can take multiple parts with different contents like file and/or JSON.

Comment: @ripunjoym1998 I am sorry to give you wrong answer.And thanks for your question, I learn much from it.