# MultipartFile Entity One To One Relationship Sending Request With RequestBody and RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am making a news app with Spring Boot and I have a Message entity and an Image entity connected in a one to one relationship. Uploading them one by one is not a problem, but when I try to upload them at the same time it doesn't work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @Lob
    @Column
    private byte[] data;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "image")
    private Message message;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "published_at")
    private LocalDateTime publishedAt;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String summary;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10000)
    private String text;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Image image;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

```
public class MessageInquiryDto {

    private Long id;
    @NotNull(message = "Title must not be null")
    private String title;

    @NotNull(message = "Summary must not be null")
    private String summary;

    @NotNull(message = "Text must not be null")
    private String text;

    private Image image;
    // getters and setters
}
```

ImageStorageService store method:

```
public Image store(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
        Image image = new Image(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());

        return imageRepository.save(image);
    }
```

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@Operation(summary = "Publish a new message with a file", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "apiKey"))
public DetailedMessageDto create(@Valid @RequestBody MessageInquiryDto messageDto, @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
    Image image = imageStorageService.store(file);
    messageDto.setImage(image);
    
    return messageMapper.messageToDetailedMessageDto(
            messageService.publishMessage(messageMapper.messageInquiryDtoToMessage(messageDto)));
}
```

I haven't been able to send a request through Postman. The message has to be sent as JSON and the file has to be a MultipartFile.

I've even tried to separate Post and Put methods like this:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@Operation(summary = "Add image to a message", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "apiKey"))
public DetailedMessageDto addImage(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        Image image = storageService.storeWithMessage(file, id);
        Message message = messageService.findOne(id);
        message.setImage(image);
        return messageMapper.messageToDetailedMessageDto(messageService.publishMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename(), e);
    }
}
```

```
public Image storeWithMessage(MultipartFile file, Long id) throws IOException {
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    Image image = new Image(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());

    Optional<Message> message = messageRepository.findById(id);

    message.ifPresent(value -> value.setImage(image));
    message.ifPresent(messageRepository::save);

    return imageRepository.save(image);
}
```

I then get an error: "Unable to upload name_of_file.jpeg".

Comment: I have recently posted an answer to a similar issue. Please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207551/spring-controller-that-accepts-both-multipartfile-and-also-a-json-object/76209048#76209048

Comment: @Mar-Z I'm wondering if the problem is in the between RequestPart and RequestParameter annotations or between ResponseEntity<String> and DetailedMessageDto return values?